# Show Hide div on load page if, if statement is true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

You will quickly see that I'm new to this and don't have a clue. I'm going mental trying to help a friend out with this project. He wants to have a simple quote form that generates a quote to html then he will copy/paste to a private wordpress page for his client.

The form starts with if radio button is selected, div is shown

index.html:

```
 <html>
<body>
<head>
        <title>Demo Quote Creator</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input[name='animalvillas']").click(function () {
            if ($("#chkYes1").is(":checked")) {
                $("#dvanimalvillas").show();
            } else {
                $("#dvanimalvillas").hide();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function () {
        $("input[name='animalkidani']").click(function () {
            if ($("#chkYes2").is(":checked")) {
                $("#dvanimalkidani").show();
            } else {
                $("#dvanimalkidani").hide();
            }
        });
    });
        </script>


</head>
<h2>Client Name</h2>
<form name="create" action="welcome.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
 <strong>Last</strong>: <input type="text" name="last" required />, <strong>First</strong>: <input type="text" name="first" required />
<BR />

<h2><strong>Resorts to Include in Quote</strong></h2>

<span><strong>Animal Kingdom Villas</strong></span><BR />
<label for="chkYes1">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes1" name="animalvillas" />
    Include
</label>
<label for="chkNo1">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo1" name="animalvillas" />
    Exclude
</label>
<hr />
<div id="dvanimalvillas" style="display: none">
$<input type="text" name="ages" size="7" /> - Value Studio - Standard View (Parking View) | Studio Description: 316sf - One (1) queen bed and one (1) double-size sleeper sofa (Sleeps 4) <br>
</div>

<span><strong>Animal Kingdom Kidani</strong></span><BR />
<label for="chkYes2">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes2" name="animalkidani" />
    Include
</label>
<label for="chkNo2">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo2" name="animalkidani" checked />
    Exclude
</label>
<hr />
<div id="dvanimalkidani" style="display: none">
$<input type="text" name="ages" size="7" /> - Value Studio - Standard View (Parking View) | Studio Description: 316sf - One (1) queen bed and one (1) double-size sleeper sofa (Sleeps 4) <br>
</div>


<BR />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, on the welcome.php, he only wants the relevent  that was selected on the index.html. Obviously, this is not working, but hopefully you can see what we are trying to accomplish.

welcome.php

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="dvanimalvillas" <?php
if ($("#chkNo1").is(":checked")) { echo 'style="display:none;"'; } ?>>
       The quote for Animal Kingdom Villas will show here when yes is selected
    </div>      


    <div id="dvanimalkidani" <?php
if ($("#chkNo2").is(":checked")) { echo 'style="display:none;"'; } ?>>
      The quote for Animal Kingdom Kidani will show here when yes is selected
    </div>      




</body>
```

Thank you for any direction you may have!

Comment: PHP runs server side and is enclose inbetween the <?php ... ?> markers. JavaScript runs client side, ie on the browser. Your code, in Welcome.php, looks like a mixture of PHP (because of the echo statement), JavaScript, and jQuery (a JS framework). Things like $("#chkNo1").is(":checked") won't work server side. It is not PHP, it is JS/jQuery.

Comment: I don't see any checkboxes on welcome.php.  Is your PHP code on welcome.php trying to reference checkboxes on index.html? You can look at the data POSTED to welcome.php from the form on index.html, but not the checkboxes themselves, which is what your code looks like it's trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your index.html make following changes. You have to give some value to your radio buttons to fetch in other file

```
<label for="chkYes2">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes2" name="animalkidani" value="Y" />
    Include
</label>
<label for="chkNo2">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo2" name="animalkidani"  value="N" checked />
    Exclude
</label>
```

In your welcome.php make following changes. We will use radio button value to hide and display div content.

```
<div id="dvanimalvillas" <?php echo ($_POST['animalkidani'] == "Y") ? 'style="display:none;"' : '' ; } ?>>
    The quote for Animal Kingdom Villas will show here when yes is selected
</div>      


<div id="dvanimalkidani" <?php echo ($_POST['animalkidani'] == "N") ? 'style="display:none;"' : '' ; } ?>>
    The quote for Animal Kingdom Kidani will show here when yes is selected
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm on the right direction now I believe, but I'm getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I've used ternary operator and forgot to remove closing bracket there. Edited my answer for future reference. Btw can you please accept my answer if it was helpful for resolving your issue?

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things going on here:

1. You're not using radio buttons properly.  Each radio selection needs a different value within each radio group having the same name.  This value is what is sent with the form when it is submitted.  See this link: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm
2. In welcome.php, you need to look at the form data that is sent from index.html, not at the actual checkboxes from the form.  See this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm